# mouse won't connect properly

Tags: windows-7, usb, mouse, usb-3

This is maybe a question from a lower than average level, but I figured this place was the best chance of getting an solution to my little problem...
I've bought a Sharkoon Fireglider mouse with 7 buttons and along with the mouse came some softeware to config the mouse etc. but when I plug in my mouse on my USB port it says the software doesn't support USB 3.0. Sharkoon doesn't carry out updates on this mouse editor software, or otherwise I can't find it.

Anyway, when I start a game(like COD mw3 etc.), that game doesn't detect those 3 additional mouse buttons, so I can't assign them to the controls. It doesn't matter wether I plug it in on USB 2.0 or 3.0.
However, those buttons do work in windows explorer and other system programs.
I can't select an in-game multiple button mouse option.

Long story short, games don't detect my additional mouse buttons.. 
So is there any mouse software that does support USB 3.0 or another solution to this problem?

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: Did you install the latest driver or any software that your mouse has in order to properly use it? Also try reinstalling them.

Comment: It's not the USB port that affecting the buttons, it's the crappy software the mouse manufacturer is supplying.  You can get the editor software from their site here: http://www.sharkoon.com/?q=en/content/fireglider-black - hopefully it's newer than what you've got.

Comment: You can get around this by using a USB 2.0 Hub connected to a USB 3.0 port.